# SharePoint Online: Problem opening Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, office-web-apps

1. SharePoint Online
2. Excel 2010
3. Internet Explorer 11

I've recently completed a SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint Online upgrade and am dealing with a few user issues in the project's wake.  One user in particular is having some problems with opening Excel spreadsheets from a standard team site.

Please see the error message below
[image: SPO Error message]

Now, I'm aware that there is a very similar error message that subs "Office Online" for "Office Web Apps" but I'm not sure to what extent these will have the same causes.

As best I can tell, there are no conflicting versions of Office installed that'll cause problems.

As such, any ideas or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: is this issue with one user only? does the user have more than one version of office installed on his machine?

Comment: Checked already.  There's no conflicting office applications on the machine.  All IE specific plugins also correspond to Office 2010

Comment: Can that user open the documents from other pc?

Comment: There are 28 other team members, none of them having this problem.  I'm confident I can restrict the issue to his IE settings, I'm just not sure which one.

Comment: what is IE version and is it 32 bit or 64 bit? what is office version and 64 or 32?

Comment: check this one as well http://blogs.technet.com/b/emeaoffice/archive/2013/04/29/you-get-an-error-message-when-you-open-an-office-file-from-sharepoint-on-a-computer-on-which-you-installed-more-than-one-version-of-office.aspx

Comment: Waqas, I think you'll recall me from Technet, I know what to search for.  Nothing has worked in that last link.  He can check items in/out quite fine in Chrome but not within IE.

Comment: see, as we all dont have access to your environment, No details other than you shared then it is very hard to give you exact answer. So all our resolution is based on counter questions.....the information we get and give the user direction. I know people come here after doing all the searchs but some time they overlooked an issue.

Comment: So, I would try to check the User pc(add/remove programm), Clear the browser Cache, try with other browser, click on the troubleshoot button. If you have more detail then shared with us.